# Resque and New relic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, resque, newrelic

I've started getting strange errors with New Relic and resque

```
INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
ERROR : undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass: Unable to send data to parent process, please see https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/resque-instrumentation for more information
```

I have followed the instructions [here](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/resque-instrumentation)

I am also no longer seeing anything in my new relic control panel

Comment: I got in touch with the guys at New Relic about a week ago. They asked for a load of files which I sent. Not heard back since. :(

Comment: Same issue here, too. I'm running resque-pool, version 0.3.0. Anybody using resque-pool, too?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the New Relic Ruby agent?

Comment: Where do you see these messages?

Comment: Answering my own question: I think you're seeing them in `log/newrelic_agent.log` within the app's folder.

Answer (score 0):

The [directions](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/resque-instrumentation) have been updated recently. I believe `:report_instance_busy => false` was moved from `Resque.before_first_fork` to `Resque.after_fork`.

Alternatively, if you are able to bump `resque` to `>= 1.23.1` then you can remove the explicit `resque` hooks altogether as `resque` chaining has been fixed and the `newrelic_rpm` gem instructions will not be overwritten by other gems.

If these fixes don't work, you might want to [turn on audit logging](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/audit-log) in your newrelic.config.  You only want this on for a brief period of time (say 5 minutes) as it may adversely affect your application's performance.  You can attach this to the `newrelic` issue request and/or possibly figure out what's wrong by reading the file yourself.

Comment: The current version of the `resque` gem is 1.25.2 so I'm not sure what you mean by bumping `resque` to `~> 3.0.0`.

Comment: Yeah not sure why I put 3.0.0... that appears to be the redis gem.  But it's not meaningful in this context.  I updated my post.